# How to find the maximum depth of the tree for each node (branch)

Tags: linux, bash, tree

I'm trying to retrieve the maximum depth of a main branch in a tree. For example:

If I execute "pactree -a gdm" in an Arch Linux distribution, I'll get something like this:

```
gdm
|-gnome-shell
||-accountsservice
|||-glib2
||||-pcre
|||||-gcc-libs
||||| `-glibc provides glibc>=2.27
|||||   |-linux-api-headers provides linux-api-headers>=4.10
|||||   |-tzdata
|||||   `-filesystem
|||||     `-iana-etc
|||||-readline
||||||-glibc
||||||-ncurses
|||||| |-glibc
|||||| `-gcc-libs
|||||`-ncurses provides libncursesw.so=6-64
```

I would like to return for  the "gnome-shell" branch something like this:

`gnome-shell:7`

Since `` "`-iana-etc" `` is the deepest child node at 7 levels
One issue here is that I need to look at all the sub-nodes using either "|"(pipe) and `` "`" `` (backtick) since either of them may have another sub-node.

I was trying to achieve this with awk but couldn't figure out how to specify  "one-character-long" FIELDS.

Kindly, could you please provide some basic script that could serve as a starting point to achieve my goal, and also let me know if awk is the best tool for this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a start for you to consider:

```
$ awk -F'[`|]' '{ print NF,$0}' input
1 gdm
2 |-gnome-shell
3 ||-accountsservice
4 |||-glib2
5 ||||-pcre
6 |||||-gcc-libs
7 ||||| `-glibc provides glibc>=2.27
7 |||||   |-linux-api-headers provides linux-api-headers>=4.10
7 |||||   |-tzdata
7 |||||   `-filesystem
7 |||||     `-iana-etc
6 |||||-readline
7 ||||||-glibc
7 ||||||-ncurses
8 |||||| |-glibc
8 |||||| `-gcc-libs
7 |||||`-ncurses provides libncursesw.so=6-64
```

It looks like I wound up with the same result as you did:  iana-etc is at level 7.  However, I have a different conclusion:  glibc and gcc-libs are the deepest items at level 8.

Ideally, this information should get you started on completing this programming task.

I think that awk is a very reasonable choice for this.

Comment: Thank you Mark!   Sorry, I couldn't reply until now.